# Use private podspec repo only with Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

I host a private podspec repo internally, and I would like to use Cocoapods without depending on the public master spec repo. Is there a way to remove dependency on the master spec repo entirely?

The issue is that my company is frozen at cocoapods 0.34.1, and cannot update in time. However, recent changes to the master repo require a min version of 0.35.0. Any time I try to run any pod command, I get the following message.

`[!] The "master" repo requires CocoaPods 0.35.0 -  (currently using 0.34.1)`

I understand what that means, and would like to remove the master repo as a dependency altogether, but it seems like that isn't an option. Any insights?

Comment: We are having the same problem. Thanks for posting this and your comment on the commit on github.  And I created a ticket: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/13170

Comment: @Hugh checkout my answer below. Bit of a hack, but might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This created quite the fire drill for us today. We ended up changing our build scripts to run a custom `pod install` alias, which rolls back the min version in the CocoaPods-version.yml.

`alias myPodInstall="sed -i -e 's/min: 0.35.0/min: 0.34.0/' ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/CocoaPods-version.yml; pod install"`

Definitely a hack, but it unblocked us as we push for our release. Perhaps this helps others out there in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. It's a novel workaround for an unfortunate situation. I hope the Cocoapods team can do better in communicating changes and establishing better process for version updates.